# How to always return 'changed' or 'ok' for a task

Tags: ansible

I am running a playbook to kill processes. When there are no processes to kill, 'Now killing' task doesn't return anything. How can I force it to return 'changed' or 'ok'?

I already tried setting 'changed_when: True',  but it didn't work.

```
- hosts: WORK
  gather_facts: no
  pre_tasks:
    - setup:
        gather_subset: min
  tasks:
    - name: Get running processes @weight 1
      shell:
        ps -fu `whoami` |grep -v $$ |grep -v PID |grep -v sshd |grep -v ansible |grep -v $$ |awk '{print $2}'
      register:
        running_processes

    - name: Now killing
      command:
        kill -9 {{ item }}
      with_items:
        "{{ running_processes.stdout_lines }}"
```

```
PLAY [WORK] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [tstqat36_qatwrk90]

TASK [Get running processes @weight 1] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [tstqat36_qatwrk90]

TASK [Now killing] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
tstqat36_qatwrk90          : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: You're passing an empty list to `with_items`. With no items over which to iterate, the task is never run.  It is neither `changed` nor `okay`; it simply hasn't been executed.

Comment: I know. That's why I asked if there is any way to force it to return 'change' or 'ok'.

Comment: There is not, because it's not running.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you could do something hacky like this, but I don't think it's a good idea:

```
- name: Now killing
  shell: |
      [ "{{ item }}" != __flag__ ] && kill -9 "{{ item }}"
  register: result
  failed_when: result.rc != 0 and item != "__flag__"
  changed_when: result.rc == 0 and item != "__flag__"
  with_items:
    - __flag__
    - "{{ running_processes.stdout_lines }}"
```

This will always report "ok" once regardless of whether or not there are items in `running_processes.stdout_lines`.